# How to call single item with DynamoDB?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm trying to call `getItem` to DynamoDB. I'm using code samples from the documentation, however, all that I'm getting is *null*.

- I have a table called `table`.
- I have table row with Primary partition key called `id` (number).
- I don't have Primary sort key.
- Lambda function has the permission of `Allow: dynamodb:GetItem`

My `item` with `id` of `123` has few more rows attached to it, and I'd like to retrieve them all in the console log.

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({ region: 'eu-central-1' });

exports.handler = async (event) => {

  // Create the DynamoDB service object
  ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: '2012-10-08' });

  var params = {
    TableName: 'table',
    Key: {
      'id': { N: '123' },
    }
  };

  // Call DynamoDB to read the item from the table
  ddb.getItem(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error", err);
    } else {
      console.log("Success", data.Item);
    }
  });

};
```

Comment: so what is cosole.log producing ?

Comment: @guzial I'm not getting any of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => { 
// Create the DynamoDB service object
ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-10-08'});

var params = {
  TableName: 'TABLE',
  Key: {
    'KEY_NAME' : {N: '123'},
  },
  ProjectionExpression: 'ATTRIBUTE_NAME'
};

// Call DynamoDB to read the item from the table

ddb.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Success", data.Item);
  }
});
}
```

This is my lambda example you can try it.

Comment: you Are not using `exports.handler`?

Comment: this is simple node ...but you can add this inside exports.handler..and without handle code obvious not run on lambda

Comment: Can you provide an example that would run on Lambda? That's the part with which I have issues. Your current example in nearly same to what I posted in the question. Thank you.

Comment: @curious sorry i was busy..now free is it worked ? or now i can give you proper answer

Comment: that's great ...my pleasure...any time up for help aws and docker angular and node

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186036/discussion-between-curious-and-harsh-manvar).

Answer (score 1):

This is example from my lambda function (please change execution env to Node.js 6.10 and table and id names and values). This works, and logs some information. Please try...

```
'use strict';

const aws = require('aws-sdk'); 
const dbCon = new aws.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var params = {
        TableName: "trans",
        Key: {
            "transid": {"S": "Bk6ZQF0Q7"}
        }
    };

    console.log("Attempting a call getitem...");

    dbCon.getItem(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to getItem. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        }
        else {
            console.log("getItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        }
    });

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    }; 

    callback(null, response); 
};
```

Comment: Thank you kind soul. I'll check it out tomorrow

Comment: ooo :) i see you accepted answer written later which is same as mine :)

Comment: Oh dang, I owe you karma. Sorry about that. Catch a beer instead 

Answer (score 0):

Your getItems call is asynchronous and your Lambda function is finishing before your dynamodb call returns with the result, hence why nothing is being logged. Your actual database call is probably working fine.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/calling-services-asynchronously.html